# NPM warning requires peer dependency that must be installed by self / updating node

Tags: npm, react-dom

When trying to install material icons i receive these errors:

npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @material-ui/core@4.11.0: wanted: {"node":">=8.0.0"} (current: {"node":"6.10.3","npm":"6.14.4"})

npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @material-ui/core@4.11.0

npm WARN @material-ui/core@4.11.0 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.8.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Does anyone know what to do in order to fix the issue?

Comment: Could you please update your question by providing the command you're running? I would suggest you to give more details to fully understand your issue.